# opensips sip invite header forward with string instead of number

Tags: opensips

I am trying to forward call from opensips to PBX. but opensips is forward call with below invite

```
INVITE sip:s@197.237.56.175:5160 SIP/2.0
Record-Route: <sip:41.72.194.63;lr;did=bb.b18255a4>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 41.72.194.63:5060;branch=z9hG4bK4ee8.d7681d24.1
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 41.72.194.48;received=41.72.194.48;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKUttKpDXZ34XUS
Max-Forwards: 28
From: "Ankit" <sip:25420570101@41.72.194.48>;tag=6Bjgy3y22Nvpm
To: <sip:254205700263@41.72.194.63>
```

Here issue in 1st line its forward invite with s@ip but i want to convert into number@ip like 254205700263@ip

Any ideas,Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your OpenSIPS script, you can use the `$rU` variable, which will directly overwrite the "username" part. Here is an example:

```
...
$rU = "254205700263";
...
t_relay(); # send it out
```

The [core variables](http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Script-CoreVar-2-4) may prove to be a useful learning tool, especially if you're new to the script.

Comment: Thanks For reply,Let me try

Comment: I have question i dont want to set manually number but i wish it will be same as to number.
So is it possible ?

Comment: Under which function i have to put that ?

Comment: Change to `$rU = $tU;`